# How can I scrobble my music plays from the Zune desktop software to last.fm?

Tags: music, zune, zune-software, last.fm

I recently started using the Zune desktop software to play my music, and I really like it. Once thing that I need in all my music players, however, is the ability to scrobble to last.fm. I'm having trouble finding a simple way to do this that isn't out of date.

How can I scrobble my music plays from the Zune desktop software to last.fm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First Download and Install [Last.FM scrobbler](http://www.last.fm/download), then you will have to install [ZuseMe](https://code.google.com/p/zuseme-lastfm/downloads/list). While Installing Zuse, choose the folder where you have Zune installed to

Installation Instructions
 1. Install the latest Zune Desktop Software.
 2. Install the Last.fm client and login (Allow scrobbling from all harddrives)
 3. Make sure that you installed the requirements (.NET Framework 4 / Visual C++)
 4. Extract the ZuseMe directory to any directory you want.
 5. Launch ZuseMe.exe (Runs hidden in the background/tray menu)

Comment: This leads me to wonder about zune plugin development. last.fm scrobblers are pretty easy to write. I haven't used the zune software for my media in a long time (i used fb2k and then moved to linux), but there's no reason to install anything from last.fm to scrobble there.